# Adding last value from Database as text in Wordpress Page

Tags: database, updates

How to grab the last value of a database I have in Wordpress (accessible through myphpadmin or similar) and display it as part of a line of text on one of my pages? For example, the database has the latest number of "win" and "Loss" for a team, and I want one of my Wordpress pages to display the following text and that it always stays updated automatically.

Text example: Team X has won "enter here win number" games and lost "enter here loss number"games.

I just want to display that number as text inside my sentence, but have only found how to add the complete table.

I prefer a plugin if possible rather than changing/adding code.

Comment: What you want is too specific to have it as a plugin. Rather spend your time figuring out basic mysql / php functionality.

Comment: @funkysoul Thanks for the answer. Does that mean that I can write an SQL query in the wordpress page directly and call the value in the database? That is the part I don't know if it is possible.